# How do I take a leave of absence due to stress?

Tags: leave-of-absence

I'm currently experiencing a lot of stress and I'd like/need to take a month or two off work, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

What do I tell my boss? I want to leave asap.
I should've brought this up earlier, but how can I approach this from this point on?

Comment: I don't get your question. If you need a month off due to stress, then you tell that to your manager. What else can you tell him, and why do you think you have to tell him something else?

Comment: This is really country and company specific.  You will have to talk to your HR department.  Voting to close!

Comment: If you're in the US, the [FMLA](http://www.dol.gov/whd/fmla/) might apply.

Comment: The effects of stress are considered to be a form of illness or innjury in many jurisdictions. Consult your doctor about the stress and consult your sickness policy about the procedure, in just the same way as if you had any other injury. Consider also how you plan to deal with the source of the stress.

Answer (score 5):

You tell your boss that you really need a break, and ask whether, in addition to burning all your vacation time now, there's any way you can get some additional unpaid time off.

Unless you've been with the company for years at least, and have been maintaining a good performance level, don't expect them to say yes.

Note that if you don't have a good reason for why you're stressed out, this raises questions about whether you can handle this job. The right answer may be to look at the stress rather than time off.

Comment: I will add that if the stress is in your personal life, you need to level with your boss and tell him what is going on. You are asking for something extraordinary from him, you have to tell him why you need it.